# why is my variable "value" always undefined?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a callback function and i  want it to retun the  value and assign it to  my variable "value"

```
function a(callback){
     // let elecfirebase=[]
      firebase
          .database()
          .ref("/fournisseurs")
          .child(0)
          .child("data")
          .on("value", data => {
           let  elecfirebase=data.val(); 
            callback(elecfirebase);
        });

  }

let value= a( function(elecfirebase){
    return (elecfirebase)}
  );

console.log(value)
```

Comment: `value` gets set to the return value of `a`, which itself doesn't return anything. See the link above to manage this

Comment: i read this post, but i don't have the solution for a() returning value!

Comment: You can use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/490az8xm/2/)

Comment: Thanks you very much, it's good when i use console.log
When i do `let val=a.then(function(value) {return(value); // returning value});`
i have this output 
`Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(4)`
how can i access to  [[PromiseValue]] ?

Comment: You can only access the value within the callback of .then, you can’t access outside. You’ll need to do your logic inside of the .then callback, or, if you use your original code, you’ll have to do your logic with value inside the function you pass to `a`